# Laravel Vuejs pass data from blade to .vue template

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I am new in Vuejs. I have the following code and i am getting an error. I am trying to pass a var into vue file.

What do i do wrong? And how can i achieve this?

App.js:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.component('formlements' ,require('./components/formelements/Input.vue') );
const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app'
});
```

Blade:

```
<formlements :testinfo="{somekey: 'someinfo'}"></formlements>
```

Vue file

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        {{testinfo.somekey}}
    </div>
</template>
```

Error:

Property or method "testinfo" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property

Comment: That's because you haven't defined it as a prop in your app/component, something like `props: { testinfo: <type> }`. Can you show us the full component file for `formelements`?

Comment: @Terry this was the correct answer export default {
        props: { testinfo: Object }
    } Can you give it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, you have not defined `props` on your component or app. Even though you have bound the variable to the prop using `:bind`, it is still not accessible to the component.

All you need to do is declare the prop, e.g. `props: { testinfo: Object }`.